# How to post to asp.net validation required page with C# and read response

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, html-agility-pack

I am writing my own specific product crawler. Now there is a product selling website which uses post data for pages. I really really need to able to post data and read the response. But they are using asp.net validation and it is so messed up. I really could not figure how to properly post data and read. I am using htmlagilitypack. If it is possible to post data with htmlagilitypack and read the response it would be really really awesome.

Now this is the example page : http://www.hizlial.com/HizliListele.aspx?CatID=482643

When you opened the page look at the class "urun_listele"

You will see the options there

```
20 Ürün Listele
40 Ürün Listele
60 Ürün Listele
Tümünü Listele
```

Those numbers are product counts to be displayed. Tümünü listele means list all products. Now I really need to post data and get all of the products under that product category. I used firebug to debug and tried to code below but i still got default number of products

```
        private void button11_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder srBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        AppendPostParameter(srBuilder, "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cmbUrunSayi", "full");    
        srBuilder = srBuilder.Replace("&", "", srBuilder.Length - 1, 1);
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(srBuilder.ToString());
        HttpWebRequest hWebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.hizlial.com/HizliListele.aspx?CatID=482643");
        hWebReq.Method = "POST";
        hWebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        using (Stream requestStream = hWebReq.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
        HtmlDocument hd = new HtmlDocument();

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)hWebReq.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {              
                var htmlstring = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    static private void AppendPostParameter(StringBuilder sb, string name, string value)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", name, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value));
    }
```

After i get the data I will load it to the htmlagilitypack HtmlDocument

Any help is appreciated.

C# 4.0 , wpf application, htmlagiltiypack

Comment: Have you looked at using the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class it wraps a lot of the logic for you, take a look at the `UploadValues` method.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any good example of this ?

Comment: There are examples on MSDN for the method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP .Net uses `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT`  fields to simulate Windows Forms behavior. To simulate Change event of combobox on server you need to append to form field to request they are `__EVENTTARGET` as 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cmbUrunSayi' and `__EVENTARGUMENT` as ''.

If you look onchange code of combo and __doPostBack method you will understand what I mean. You can insert the code below after your declaration of srBuilder. That way code will work.

```
AppendPostParameter(srBuilder,  "__EVENTTARGET", "ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cmbUrunSayi"); 
AppendPostParameter(srBuilder, "__EVENTARGUMENT", string.Empty);
```

You will also need to extract __VIEWSTATE & __EVENTVALIDATION values. To get them just send a dummy request and extaract that values and cookies from that request and then append them into new one...

Comment: Yes i know it uses but i am asking how do i use it programmatically to make successfully post request :)

Comment: I also added __VIEWSTATE to post and keep cookies it failed :) gave 500 internal server error

Comment: Your code is ok. Just add that two lines, after 4th line and it will work.

Comment: If it needs a ViewState, just post and empty request. Get Cookies, Session and ViewState after that send a request with actual viewstate data and cookies

Comment: I solved the problem via extract __VIEWSTATE & __EVENTVALIDATION then add cookies and those values to post and submit the post. If you send empty etc it would fail. I love htmlagilitypack ^^